# Using local variable inside a function Tabletop

Tags: javascript, html, function, local-variables, tabletop.js

i'm currently using Tabletop to make a spreadsheet act like database for my blogspot

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.5.1/tabletop.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>    
  
  var publicSpreadsheetUrl = '1ZXZVfon9ywNelbVEchOu9HQbSLZJRE-x6G2xOFPA-lA';
  
  function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
                     callback: showInfo,
                     simpleSheet: true } )
  }

  function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    alert('Successfully processed!' + data.length + 'rows!')
    // console.log(data);
    var str = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
  }

  document.write("Document <a target='_new' href='" + publicSpreadsheetUrl + "'>Here</a>");
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
[enter image description here][1]
```

how to use local variable so i can print outside the function, like this

```
function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    alert('Successfully processed!' + data.length + 'rows!')
    // console.log(data);
    var str = JSON.stringify(data); 
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
  document.write("Document <a target='_new' href='" + publicSpreadsheetUrl + "'>Here</a>");
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

full link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZXZVfon9ywNelbVEchOu9HQbSLZJRE-x6G2xOFPA-lA/pubhtml

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.5.1/tabletop.min.js'></script>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script type='text/javascript'>    
  
  var publicSpreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZXZVfon9ywNelbVEchOu9HQbSLZJRE-x6G2xOFPA-lA/pubhtml';
  
  function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
                     callback: showInfo,
                     simpleSheet: true } )
  }

  function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    
    var str = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
  }

  document.write("Document <a target='_new' href='" + publicSpreadsheetUrl + "'>Here</a>");
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the problem was, and how you fixed it.

Comment: i explained, full link not id only

Comment: I assumed that was a link to code. Using full sentences would make your intent clearer.

Comment: I am weak in English - I do not mean the abbreviation in the explanation